# Convert number with decimal to hours with decimal using JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, datetime, math

Hi i'm building a little invoice program. the users enter there hours as 7.2, 7.5, 2.8 like this. but i need to convert this numbers to actual hours with decimal places

ex-  7 hours and 45 minutes equals 7.75, not 7.45. if user enter 7.45

```
var hr=7.45;
var rate=10;
subtotal =hr*rate;
alert(subtotal);
```

the application calculate as above, but it's not correct, can anyone help me to fix this
additional info.

```
7.45 x $50.00 pr hr = $372.50
7.75 x $50.00 pr hr = $387.50
1 hour = 1.00 hour
1 hour and 25 minutes = 1.25 hours
1 hour and 30 minutes = 1.50 hours
1 hour and 45 minutes = 1.75 hours
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic seem to be terribly flawed, for instance why would 1 hour and 25 minutes equal 1.25 when 1 hour and 30 minutes equals 1.5, you would think it should be closer to 1.42?

And why would the user input 2.8 when they are inputting times based on 60 minutes per hour, wouldn't 3.2 make more sense?

Anyway, I'm guessing something like this is what you're looking for

```
function deciHours(time) {
    return (function(i) {return i+(Math.round(((time-i)*60),10)/100);})(parseInt(time, 10));
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6frnD/3/)

Comment: thanks for answer the users are submitting something like
7.75 and they thought its 7 hrs and 45 minutes so i wanna know what is 7.75 has decimal part called 0.75 - from 0.75 what amount i need to multiply to get accurate subtotal. thanks

Comment: @IreshaKumari - So it's basically the other way around? Edited the answer!

Answer (score 2):

you should use split the 7.75 variable in two. save the value 7 in one variable and then multiple 0.75 * 60 = 45 and then append it to the first variable. that should work.